# Best kind of battery for electric motorcycle?

Tags: batteries, battery-chemistry

I want to try and build a DIY electric motorcycle, but am having issues finding the right batteries to use.

I've tried searching for this online but there is surprisingly little information about the batteries themselves.

Ultimately I am aiming for a range of 60km, top speed of 80kph for a payload of 200kg (rider and bike). I am looking at a 48V/150 amps DC motor.

Would anyone know what kind of batteries I should be looking for (doesn't have to be a brand, just the right type, size and number)?

Comment: An electric motorcycle battery??

Comment: Yeah.  I saw some.  But they usually require a massive battery pack. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To go 80 kph you will need about 6 kW of power output, depending on your aerodynamics and rolling resistance. Divide by the overall efficiency (electrics, motor) of your drivetrain, say 0.8 if all components fit well. This ends up being around 7.5 kW electrical load.

You want to go for about an hour, meaning you have to carry at least 7.5kWh if you allow your batteries to be fully drained when you arrive. 
It is advisable to drain the batteries less, because they tend to last much longer if only regularly drained below a certain threshold, very much depending on the type of battery.

Now let´s look at the power densities of batteries. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rechargeable_battery

- Good Lead batteries end up at about 40 Wh/kg, working out to at least 187.5 kg of lead batteries.
- Lithium-Ion are about 4x that, meaning you need only about 50kg of those.
- LiFePO, which are recommended for vehicles, are about 3x better than Lead: about 70kg.

Mind you, that is the absolute least weight, completely draining the batteries after 1 hour. I advise going quite a bit bigger.

7.5 kWh at 48V works out to be 156.25 Ah.

Comment: Ah so would a few of these do? http://www.ebay.com/itm/48V-10AH-LiFePo4-Battery-Electric-Bicycle-Scooter-E-Bike-Rechargeable-Free-ship-/251720427942

Comment: Yes, 15 of those.

Answer (score 3):

Lead or LiPo battery are available for such configurations.  You could use 4 "small" motorcycle lead batteries or a bunch of LiPo batteries.  In either case, you'll end up with quite a large battery pack, so you have to consider available space.

All your specifications are correlated, but not directly related to the battery pack: you need specifications of DC motor to estimate your range and maximum payload you may get.  First of all, your motor's torque curve won't be a straight line, it is a kind of S curve that ends in a parabola going downward.  Concretely, that means that you will need a base amount of current just to start moving and then the amount of current to accelerate is greater than the amount required to hold at 80kph.  You have to check you real world usage to determine your battery pack size.  If you are in a city stopping frequently, you'll end up using a lot more power than if you are going constantly at 80kph for 60km on a road/highway.

If I were you, I'll start looking into that first, because you look like you haven't considered that.  Those factors will determine the mAh rating required for your battery pack, which will determine the actual size of the battery pack and finally the actual range that you can realistically target for a given battery pack size.  Sure you can get a very large battery pack, but it will have a significant weight and price...

Answer (score -1):

check on eBay for old laptop batteries, many times they are just AA batteries soldiered together into cells, and as no one want a battery from a laptop 5 years ago, you can get them cheap break the plastic coating off, and there you go!
thats new you can get them used even cheaper!!
Lithium ion
keep in mind battery technology has changed a lot, new Li ion batterris can charge 1000's of times faster than previous versions, some can hold 100X the power.
and suffer based are more "green" and better.

Comment: He's searching for the best kind of batteries for his motorcycle. Not the cheapest.

Comment: Even old -- this is a garbage answer.  18650s are not AAs, new batteries cannot charge 1000's of times faster than old ones, and no battery technology has grown 100x in energy density.